# How to read string from printwriter from java server to swift client through stream

Tags: swift5

i am new in swift i want read string from java server through stream in swift but its giving me -1
here is my server code in java

```
PrintWriter out = null;
                        try {
                            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                    new OutputStreamWriter(tempClientSocket.getOutputStream())),
                                    true);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                       out.println("hello world");

here is my client code in swift

     let data ="hello".data(using: .utf8)!
            let dataCount = data.count
            let bytesWritten = data.withUnsafeBytes { (p: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Int in
                       return streams.outputStream.write(p, maxLength: dataCount)
            }
```

but its reading i think in bytes thats why byteswritten is coming -1 i want to see "hello world" in byteswritten